# How to run ASP.NET 5 web site using CoreCLR in Azure Web App?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, kudu, coreclr

I am creating an ASP.NET 5 Web API application that I want to host in Azure as a Web App. I want to target only `dnxcore50` framework, but it seems that Azure Web App uses full DNX CLR when running ASP.NET 5 applications:

[image]

Because of that my application has to target both `dnxcore50` and `dnx451` frameworks. When I target only `dnxcore50` I get an deployment error saying that my app doesn't support full DNX CLR:

> The project being published does not support the runtime dnx-CLR-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final

I found [a post from 2014](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2014/11/asp-net-5-on-azure-websites/) that suggests that there is an `*.ini` file in the `approot` folder that can be modified to change the CLR version, but I can't find it.

Is there a way to run an ASP.NET 5 app as Azure Web App using CoreCLR?

Answer (score 4):

When you publish using `dnu publish`, pass the argument `--runtime <name of runtime>` to specify what runtime to use or `--framework <name of framework>` to specify a framework.

The difference between the two is that `--framework` doesn't include the runtime in the output package folder.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use the `dnu` tool to publish. Was using git before.

Comment: In that case you can specify a different runtime in `global.json`

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Are you saying that we can use Git and also use CoreCLR?

Comment: How does one specify a different runtime in the `global.json` file?  I also am using git deploy and getting an error like the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with GitHub deploy (and presumably other deployment mechanisms) add a `global.json` to the root of your repository with the following (update the `version` as appropriate)

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
    "runtime": "coreclr"
  }
}
```